# Encrypt Password Before Form Submit

Tags: php, javascript

We have a simple HTML page which includes one form with two fields: username & password.

The form submits to a PHP page.

When I post the form, the password should be encrypted not as a plain text.

If a user enters password as “abc”, then after post & get that value it should be encrypted.

Comment: Why do you need to have your form work this way? If you want enchanced security, wouldn't it be better to use an HTTPS connection for your website?

Answer (score 4):

You can't encrypt a password for transmission...

unless you use SSL.

If you don't use the https protocol, it won't be encrypted.

You can encrypt the password for storage at the server. That means that it can't be decrypted once stored, and therefore, the user can't get the plaintext password back.

However, if somebody intercepts the transmission, the password will be plaintext unless SSL is used. If you use SSL, you need to pay to get an SSL certificate.

Alternatively, you can create a self-signed SSL certificate. However, many browsers will complain and tell the user it is an insecure site, until the user clicks to confirm that they want to visit the site, even though it is insecure.

Otherwise try http://www.cacert.org/ for free SSL certificates. But free certificates are normally still not well recognized by browsers.

Comment: We don't have HTTPS. https://www.onlinesbi.com/retail/login.htm. They have encrypted password with Javascript before submit page

Comment: Encrypting passwords with javascript DOESN'T WORK. The reason is that the encrypted password effectively becomes THE password. Somebody can tamper with the javascript, so that if they know the encrypted password, it gets transmitted to your server, without the javascript trying to encrypt it again

Comment: The link you gave goes to a bank, which is on https. Since they have SSL, passwords through that webpage are encrypted properly.